# My Procedure is not calling in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have this procedure which is created successfully. but not showing result

```
delimiter ;;

drop procedure if exists test2;;

create procedure test2()

begin

select ‘Hello World’;

end

;;
```

I am calling this as

```
  CALL test2();
```

This is showing this error

```
 #1054 - Unknown column '‘Hello' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is done as following

```
SELECT routine_definition
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE routine_name =  'procedurename'
AND routine_schema =  'dbname'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you're using the `‘` character instead of `'` when creating the SELECT statement.

When I run your SELECT query using `‘`, it fails with the error message you describe; using the straight quote `'` it works properly.